# How to remove 'Volunteers' menu option where it's not appropriate?

Tags: 4.7, civivolunteer

I want users who have no access to CiviVolunteer functions to **not** have this menu option available to them.  However the 'Volunteers' menu doesn't appear in the 'Navigation Menu' in the 'Administer' option, so can't be modified.  Is there some other way of achieving this?  Civi 4.7.24 and CiviVolunteer 2.2.2

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure, yet if menu comes from CiviVolunteer 2.2.2 extension, perhaps an extra permission check should be added here: 
https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/blob/59534288f37c96202434c57adc73d2fa5dc7ba55/volunteer.php#L46